# XCTAssertThrowsError for async/await function

Tags: swift, unit-testing, asynchronous, async-await, xctest

Given the following method signature, how can I test this method:

```
func doTheJob(param: String) async throws -> String
```

with `XCTAssertThrowsError`?

I've tried `XCTAssertThrowsError(await object.doTheJob(param: ""))` but getting an error:

> 'async' call in an autoclosure that does not support concurrency

What would be a solution to this problem?

Comment: XCTAssertThrowsError method is designed for synchronous code, not asynchronous code.

Comment: Yep, I know it. The question was about how to test the async method in a similar fashion if the `XCTAssertThrowsError` or similar assertion is not available for async.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be a good idea to submit a feature request for this using Feedback Assistant but for now you can create a `func` that `XCTFail` if the `expression` does not `throw`

```
func xCTAssertThrowsError<T>(_ expression: @autoclosure () async throws -> T) async {
    do {
        _ = try await expression()
        XCTFail("No error was thrown.")
    } catch {
        //Pass
    }
}
```

Then you can use it something like.

```
func testExample() async throws {

    await xCTAssertThrowsError(try await doSomething())
}
```

If you want to use the `errorHandler` and other arguments you can implement those too in your custom `func`.

```
func xCTAssertThrowsError<T>(
    _ expression: @autoclosure () async throws -> T,
    _ message: @autoclosure () -> String = "",
    file: StaticString = #filePath,
    line: UInt = #line,
    _ errorHandler: (Error) -> Void = { _ in }
) async {
    do {
        _ = try await expression()
        XCTFail(message())
    } catch {
        errorHandler(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting design with the `errorHandler`, I'll investigate

Comment: @RichardTopchii the second func is just copy and paste from the documentation you could add async to it too like the expression if you had a handler for the error during testing.

Comment: Btw, how long would the function wait?

Comment: @RichardTopchii it would be in-sync with async/await and get called in the catch, just add await to it if you add async to the handler.

Comment: Is there a chance of a hang if error is not thrown?

Comment: @RichardTopchii no, well as long as you are using async/await the right way, there are a ton of “hacks” out there that just miss the point.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I was able to refactor the codebase in the shape I wanted. More specifically, the ability to install a custom `errorHandler` and verify that the error I need is thrown was of great help!

Comment: @RichardTopchii glad to help!